# Bootstrap 3: carousel example and sticky footer example not working together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a web page having one full-width full-height carousel along with a sticky header and footer. I started with sticky footer example here:-

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

and placed my carousel with its styles (carousel.css) provided here:-

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

But its not working. When I place carousel inside `#wrap` div, its no longer remains full-width. Moreover, footer no longer remains sticky.

If anybody know how to make both of these examples work together, then please share it with me.

Here is my html file:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Sticky Footer Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="Sticky%20Footer%20Navbar%20Template%20for%20Bootstrap_files/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="bootstrap/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="Sticky%20Footer%20Navbar%20Template%20for%20Bootstrap_files/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../docs-assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Wrap all page content here -->

      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>

    <div id="wrap">
      <!-- Begin page content -->
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Carousel
        ================================================== -->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="Collections/Haya/5184.jpg" alt="First slide">
              <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>A brand which keeps you updated</h1>
              <p>Ajay-Vijay Salwar Suits brings you latest fashion designs, exclusive range and uncomparable quality.
                 Only Ajay-Vijay Salwar Suits provides you clothing right from the bollywood's choice.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse our Collection</a></p>
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="Collections/Haya/5182-A.jpg" alt="Second slide">
              <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Best quality of fabric, best comfort</h1>
              <p>Ajay-Vijay Salwar Suits gives you the best known quality of salwar suits in fabric as well as comfort.</p>
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="Collections/Haya/5183-A.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>A name you can trust on</h1>
              <p>Ajay-Vijay Salwar Suits provides you salwar suits made of best quality lightweight fabric which
                 maximizes comfort and looks.</p>
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
        </div><!-- /.carousel -->

        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
        </div>
        <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the 
viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed 
navbar has been added within <code>#wrap</code> with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>.container</code>.</p>
        <p>Back to <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="Sticky%20Footer%20Navbar%20Template%20for%20Bootstrap_files/jquery-1.js"></script>
    <script src="Sticky%20Footer%20Navbar%20Template%20for%20Bootstrap_files/bootstrap.js"></script>


</body></html>
```

Only if I comment out `#myCarousel` div and carousel.css, it works just fine.

Comment: what does sticky means?should it be fixed,even if mouse scrolls??

Comment: @3bu1, yes, exactly. It should be fixed when mouse scrolls.

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: If your carousel is going to be the full dimensions of the browser window, why would you scroll? Further, if the carousel is going to take up the full area, where should the header/footer stick to? Sounds like you might be looking to design your ui into three separate fixed parts that eliminate scrolling altogether.

Comment: ahum, unless you want to hide the header/footer and only show them on mouse movement.

Comment: @nocturns2, Its not like I want my page to be non-scrollable. I just want my carousel to be as long as the browser window height (or if it is creating confusion, lets say it can be 500px in length) and page content can come below the carousel.

Comment: I was having the same issue as yours, what worked for me was an alternative sticky footer, http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/